# Data binding does not work in dynamic feature module, causing null pointer exception when referring to binding's views

Tags: android, android-databinding, dynamic-feature-module

I have a [dynamic features module](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/play-feature-delivery) called `favorite`. This module has an install-time delivery. In this module, I am using data binding. However, when I want to access the ID of a view, it says that the view is null.

Take a look at the XML layout present in my `favorite` module that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:colorBackground">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/frag_favorite_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="@dimen/keyline_0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/frag_favorite_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frag_favorite_tab_layout" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

As you can see, there are two views there with their respective IDs. Then, I want to reference those views in my `favorite` module fragment. I did it like this.

```
class FavoriteFragment : BaseFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragFavoriteBinding
    private val viewmodel: FavoriteViewModel by viewModel()
    override var bottomNavigationViewVisibility = View.VISIBLE

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragFavoriteBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        loadKoinModules(viewModelModule)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupViewPager()
        observeNavigationEvent()
    }

    private fun setupViewPager() {
        val viewPagerAdapter =
            FavoriteViewPagerAdapter(
                childFragmentManager,
                viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle
            )
        // THIS PART OVER HERE v
        binding.fragFavoriteViewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.fragFavoriteTabLayout, binding.fragFavoriteViewPager) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> tab.text = getString(ResR.string.movie_toolbar_text)
                1 -> tab.text = getString(ResR.string.show_toolbar_text)
            }
        }.attach()
        binding.fragFavoriteViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING || state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING)
                    EspressoIdlingResource.increment()
                else
                    EspressoIdlingResource.decrement()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun observeNavigationEvent() {
        viewmodel.navigateToDetails.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it.first != -1) {
                val action =
                    if (it.second == ListFragment.TYPE_MOVIE) FavoriteFragmentDirections.actionFavoriteFragmentToMovieDetailsFragment2(
                        it.first
                    )
                    else FavoriteFragmentDirections.actionFavoriteFragmentToShowDetailsFragment2(it.first)
                findNavController().navigate(action)
                viewmodel.finishNavigatingToDetails()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I am referencing the ViewPager using `binding.fragFavoriteViewPager` as can be seen above. During build time, there is no error. However, in run time, when I try to navigate to this `FavoriteFragment`, it returns a null pointer exception error. The error tells me that `binding.fragFavoriteViewPager` is a null object reference. The full error can be seen below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mobile.moviecatalogue, PID: 13131
    java.lang.NullPointerException: binding.fragFavoriteViewPager must not be null
        at com.mobile.favorite.ui.FavoriteFragment.setupViewPager(FavoriteFragment.kt:50)
        at com.mobile.favorite.ui.FavoriteFragment.onViewCreated(FavoriteFragment.kt:40)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1199)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2236)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2009)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1965)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1861)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mobile.moviecatalogue, PID: 13131
    java.lang.NullPointerException: binding.fragFavoriteViewPager must not be null
        at com.mobile.favorite.ui.FavoriteFragment.setupViewPager(FavoriteFragment.kt:50)
        at com.mobile.favorite.ui.FavoriteFragment.onViewCreated(FavoriteFragment.kt:40)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1199)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2236)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2009)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1965)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1861)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have set up my Gradle file for that `favorite` module like so.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

apply from: '../shared_dependencies.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobile.favorite"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    implementation project(":app")
    implementation project(":res")
}
```

To navigate to that dynamic feature fragment, in my other module called `app`, I have this navigation graph.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/movieFragment">

    ...
    <fragment
        app:moduleName="favorite"
        android:id="@+id/favoriteFragment"
        android:name="com.mobile.favorite.ui.FavoriteFragment"
        android:label="@string/favorite_toolbar_text"
        tools:layout="@layout/frag_favorite">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favoriteFragment_to_movieDetailsFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/movieDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favoriteFragment_to_showDetailsFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/showDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    ...
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_favoriteFragment"
        app:destination="@id/favoriteFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
</navigation>
```

I did the changes to the navigation graph based on [Android's doc regarding dynamic navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-dynamic). I then deleted all codes related to the call of `binding.AnyView` and used Layout Inspector. It turns out that all the views did not have any ID anymore. See this picture below.

[image]

Why did the ID disappear in Layout Inspector? What can I do to be able to reference the views using data binding in the fragment file?

**EDIT**

Using `binding.root.findViewById`, I can access the views. This is weird.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution in the Edit, same problem for me so I'll stick to findViewById...

Comment: @MerthanE I still hope that someone can provide an answer while not using `findViewById`, though, because using [`binding` should allow us to extract views faster](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding).

Comment: even findViewById not work on my code